# How to use foreach in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to convert a list of pairs to two lists – first containing first elements of the pairs, second containing second elements of the pairs.

E.g.

```
[['Test1', 'US'], ['Test1', 'France'], ['Test2', 'German']]
```

should produce

```
List1 = ['Test1', 'Test1', 'Test2']
List2 = ['US', 'France', 'German']
```

I tried to use `foreach` and come up with this function:

```
testfor:-
List = [['Test1', 'US'], ['Test1', 'France'], ['Test2', 'German']],
(
  foreach(X,List) do
    X=[F,S],
    append([F],[],List1),
    append([S],[],List2)
),
writeln(List1).
```

It doesn't work, I am confused. Where did I make a mistake? Of course, you can help me implement this function using your method (i.e. "don't use `foreach`").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well

```
yoba( [], [], [] ).
yoba( [[Name1, Name2] | Tail], List1, List2 ) :-
    append( [Name1], ListNew1, List1 ),
    append( [Name2], ListNew2, List2 ),
    yoba( Tail, ListNew1, ListNew2 ).
```

And

```
?- yoba([['Test1', 'US'], ['Test1', 'France'], ['Test2', 'German']], X, Y).
X = ['Test1', 'Test1', 'Test2'],
Y = ['US', 'France', 'German'].
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`maplist/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/4), the whole iteration is hidden and you have to think just about the deconstruction of a single pair.

```
%zip(?FirstList, ?SecondList, ?PairList)
zip(Fst, Snd, Pair) :- maplist(pair, Fst, Snd, Pair).

%pair(?First, ?Second, ?Pair)
pair(Fst, Snd, [Fst, Snd]).
```

Use it thus:

```
?- zip(List1, List2, [['Test1', 'US'], ['Test1', 'France'], ['Test2', 'German']]).
List1 = ['Test1', 'Test1', 'Test2'],
List2 = ['US', 'France', 'German'].
```

---

Note that this is an advanced solution, though. First, getting to know the basic recursive solutions (presented by other answers) is really useful and I recommend it. Without a good grasp of recursion, Prolog is just one big hell. Actually, `maplist` uses recursion too, it is just hidden from the caller.

Another thing to learn is how Prolog terms and unification work.

- Using `append` is completely unnecessary here. Moreover, it is harmful both performance-wise and readability-wise.
- Pairs are better represented using a functor, e.g. pair `['Test1', 'US']` becomes `pair('Test1', 'US')`. Among other benefits, it is harder to accidentally mix up pairs and triplets. Using functors is somewhat similar to using types in other languages.

  SWI-Prolog uses hyphen-minus as the functor for [pairs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/pairs.pl). Due to having an [operator declaration](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=operators), hyphen-minus can be used in infix notation, too. E.g. pair `['Test1', 'US']` becomes `'Test1'-'US'`. Infix notation is just syntactic sugar for the usual prefix notation used for other functors (i.e. `'Test1'-'US' == -('Test1', 'US')`).

Finally, the `foreach ... do` notation you tried to use looks like a [loop construct from ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/userman/umsroot023.html), which is a language derived from Prolog. SWI-Prolog does not support this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
pairs_to_lists([], [], []).

pairs_to_lists([E1-E2 | Tail], [E1 | Tail1], [E2 | Tail2]) :-
    pairs_to_lists(Tail, Tail1, Tail2).
```

Usage:

```
?- pairs_to_lists(['Test1'-'US', 'Test1'-'France', 'Test2'-'German'], L1, L2).
L1 = ['Test1', 'Test1', 'Test2'],
L2 = ['US', 'France', 'German'].
```

Some comments:

1. A list is an overkill if you know the number of elements in it, e.g. instead of `[A, B]` use `A-B` or `pair(A, B)`.
2. `append([A], L1, L2)` is the same as `L2 = [A | L1]`, the latter is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
testfor([], [], []).
testfor([[X, Y]|T1], [X|T2], [Y|T3]):-testfor(T1, T2, T3).
```